# High CPU usage of Mysqld process in Mariadb 10.3.24

Tags: performance, database, mariadb

We have migrated Our database from Mysql version 5.1.73 MyISAM to Mariadb 10.3.26 Innodb engine.
Ever since we are observing slowness in inserts and very high cpu usage of Mysqld process.

Our my.cnf is below.

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
datadir=/var/lib/mariadb/data
socket=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql.sock
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED

symbolic-links = 1

port = 3306
key_buffer_size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 500M
thread_stack = 256K
thread_cache_size = 64
query_cache_limit = 8M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
tmpdir=/var/lib/mariadb/tmp
tmp_table_size= 2GB


max_connections = 2048
expire_logs_days = 2
max_binlog_size = 100M


log_bin=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql_binary_log/mysql_binlog
server_id=1

binlog_format = mixed

read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M

# InnoDB settings
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 410G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
log_warnings = 1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid


#!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mariadb/mysql.sock
```

Please suggest if there is anything we can do to fix this .
Will Setting innodb_page_cleaners = 1 fix the CPU usage issue?

DB Size is 800GB

Regards,
Padmini

Comment: What are the specs of the host?  It had better have ~512GB+ of RAM or else you've allocated too much to MySQL.

Comment: RAM of the server is 512 GB. Regards,
Padmini

Comment: 1 day after applying Rick James tips,Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions..

I will turn off the query cache and change the commit frequency of the inserts.

Also please see the innodb status o/p for any possible findings.I have removed the ips and SQLs for security.

## *************************** 1. row ***************************
Type: InnoDB
Name:
Status:

## 2020-12-28 15:23:03 0x7f53a87e0700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

### Per second averages calculated from the last 31 seconds

### BACKGROUND THREAD

### srv_master_thread loops: 8128 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 431935 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 440060

### SEMAPHORES

### OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 30709730
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 421296865
RW-shared spins 1115208207, rounds 2687646128, OS waits 22420145
RW-excl spins 30775840, rounds 277954745, OS waits 6958561
RW-sx spins 245636, rounds 3976023, OS waits 58477
Spin rounds per wait: 2.41 RW-shared, 9.03 RW-excl, 16.19 RW-sx

### TRANSACTIONS

Trx id counter 91991569
Purge done for trx's n:o < 91770847 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 110153
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421472262604096, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421472262566152, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421472262599880, ACTIVE 3 sec sleeping before entering InnoDB
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228426, OS thread handle 139997076879104, query id 58188566  Statistics
SELECT Query
---TRANSACTION 421472262591448, ACTIVE 6 sec sleeping before entering InnoDB
mysql tables in use 1, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228425, OS thread handle 139997278693120, query id 58188561  root Statistics
SELECT
---TRANSACTION 421472262587232, ACTIVE 7 sec, thread declared inside InnoDB 4123
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228423, OS thread handle 139538942158592, query id 58188555 root Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91991569, sees < 91991569
---TRANSACTION 421472262574584, ACTIVE 25 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 4798
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228404, OS thread handle 139538945943296, query id 58186884 Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91990920, sees < 91990920
---TRANSACTION 421472262578800, ACTIVE 120 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 1141
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228335, OS thread handle 139538945132288, query id 58178904  root Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
---TRANSACTION 421472262625176, ACTIVE 243 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 1141
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228257, OS thread handle 139538941347584, query id 58176235  Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91986376, sees < 91986376
---TRANSACTION 421472262616744, ACTIVE 236 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 1141
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228254, OS thread handle 139539194201856, query id 58176270  root Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
SELECT ,
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91986377, sees < 91986377
---TRANSACTION 421472262612528, ACTIVE 247 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 1141
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228252, OS thread handle 139997285033728, query id 58175990  root Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91986373, sees < 91986373
---TRANSACTION 421472262595664, ACTIVE 311 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 1141
mysql tables in use 8, locked 1
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 228205, OS thread handle 139997077149440, query id 58173387  root Creating sort index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

### Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91985372, sees < 91985372
---TRANSACTION 421472262608312, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421472262650472, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421472262583016, ACTIVE 4510 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 4879
mysql tables in use 11, locked 0
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 224972, OS thread handle 139997278963456, query id 57666902 root Sending data
SELECT Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 91770846, sees < 91770846
---TRANSACTION 421472262570368, not started sleeping before entering InnoDB
mysql tables in use 7, locked 7
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421472262561936, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)

### FILE I/O

### I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
21568038 OS file reads, 55947091 OS file writes, 5176098 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 110.61 writes/s, 12.26 fsyncs/s

### INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX

### Ibuf: size 1, free list len 327, seg size 329, 29895 merges
merged operations:
insert 310690, delete mark 2804937, delete 98025
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 468 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 4886 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 1174 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 804827 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 206 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 11802 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 10235 buffer(s)
Hash table size 108898523, node heap has 6018 buffer(s)
2282.60 hash searches/s, 168.19 non-hash searches/s

### LOG

### Log sequence number 1631035877442
Log flushed up to   1631035877442
Pages flushed up to 1631035877442
Last checkpoint at  1631035877433
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
30700890 log i/o's done, 55.68 log i/o's/second

### BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY

### Total large memory allocated 449826521088
Dictionary memory allocated 209792
Buffer pool size   26868120
Free buffers       2315898
Database pages     23712605
Old database pages 8753125
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 18707, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 21568383, created 2144222, written 23631157
0.00 reads/s, 0.74 creates/s, 50.68 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 23712605, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]

### INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO

### ---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   3358720
Free buffers       281768
Database pages     2972171
Old database pages 1097131
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2433, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2704251, created 267920, written 7476898
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 19.42 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2972171, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   3358310
Free buffers       293950
Database pages     2959617
Old database pages 1092494
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2226, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2692983, created 266634, written 994418
0.00 reads/s, 0.03 creates/s, 1.10 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2959617, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   3358720
Free buffers       294486
Database pages     2959458
Old database pages 1092436
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2374, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2692116, created 267342, written 1400586
0.00 reads/s, 0.71 creates/s, 5.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2959458, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   3358310
Free buffers       279408
Database pages     2973878
Old database pages 1097759
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2419, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2705442, created 268436, written 5297912
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 14.42 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2973878, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   3358720
Free buffers       310866
Database pages     2942617
Old database pages 1086219
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2189, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2671221, created 271396, written 4720179
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 9.35 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2942617, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   3358310
Free buffers       282190
Database pages     2971125
Old database pages 1096743
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2410, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2702315, created 268810, written 1055279
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.58 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2971125, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   3358720
Free buffers       287692
Database pages     2966288
Old database pages 1094957
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2430, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2701700, created 264588, written 1357268
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.19 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2966288, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   3358310
Free buffers       285538
Database pages     2967451
Old database pages 1095386
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2226, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2698355, created 269096, written 1328617
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.55 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 2967451, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]

### ROW OPERATIONS

### 8 queries inside InnoDB, 3 queries in queue
8 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=4487, Main thread ID=139539341866752, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 149186838, updated 39010, deleted 921469, read 233065780693
27.03 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 2432.12 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s

## END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

Temp Table stmt:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test
SELECT 'testData',
data_test.a_id as a_id,
data_test.d_name_id as d_name_id,
data_test.c_id as c_id,
data_test.b_id as b_id,
data_test.meas_e_name_id as meas_e_name_id,
data_test.recipe_id as recipe_id,
MIN(data_test.date_time) as "start",
MAX(data_test.date_time) as "end",
ep,
COUNT(*) as f,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(bottom)

Answer (score 0):

For ACID, InnoDB (unlike MyISAM) takes action to avoid loss of data.  This includes a disk hit per transaction.  (Yes, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` softens that blow.)

What is probably happening is that you are inserting one row at a time with `autocommit=ON`?  How many inserts/second are you doing?

Plan A:  `BEGIN; several inserts; COMMIT;`  -- Recommend 100-1000 at a time.

Plan B:  Batch `INSERT` -- `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ...`

Plan C:  For quite high ingestion rates, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Other issues...

- The Query cache should probably be turned off.  *Every* write to a table causes *all* entries in the QC for that table to be purged.  A high ingestion rate implies that the QC is useless (for that table).
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for possible other tips.